# Swift - How return Value from HealthKit class

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, healthkit

I am a complete beginner and am just playing with HealthKit. Maybe you can answer the following question for me:

I have the following two classes:

//UIViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var BloodPressure: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    HealthControlAccess()
    
    let healthValue = HealthValue()
    healthValue.bloodPressureDiastolic()
    print (healthValue.averageDiastolic)

   }
}
```

//HealthValue

```
class HealthValue {

var averageDiastolic = 0

func bloodPressureDiastolic() {
    
    print ("bloodPressureDiastolic")
    
    let store = HKHealthStore()
    
    guard let bloodPressureDiastolic = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .bloodPressureDiastolic) else {
        // This should never fail when using a defined constant.
        fatalError("*** Unable to get the step count type ***")
    }
    
    let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: bloodPressureDiastolic, predicate: nil,limit: Int(HKObjectQueryNoLimit), sortDescriptors: nil) {
        
        query, results, error in
        
        guard let samples = results as? [HKQuantitySample] else {
            // Handle any errors here.
            return
        }
        
        var pressureDiastolic : String
        var pressureDiastolicArray : [Int] = Array()

        for sample in samples {

            pressureDiastolic = "\(sample.quantity)"
            pressureDiastolicArray.append(Int(pressureDiastolic.split(separator: " ")[0])!)
        }

        if pressureDiastolicArray.count > 0 {

            self.averageDiastolic = pressureDiastolicArray.sum()/pressureDiastolicArray.count

        }

    }

    store.execute(query)
    
}
```

I initialize the HealthValue class via the ViewController, but I don't have the value of the variable healthValue.averageDiastolic output.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

HKSampleQuery is asynchronous. You need to wait for it to complete before accessing the result. Typically this is done with a completion handler:

```
func bloodPressureDiastolic(completion: (Double) -> Void) {

    ... Current code ...

    let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: bloodPressureDiastolic, predicate: nil,limit: Int(HKObjectQueryNoLimit), sortDescriptors: nil) {

        ... Current code ...

        if pressureDiastolicArray.count > 0 {
            self.averageDiastolic = pressureDiastolicArray.sum()/pressureDiastolicArray.count
        }

        Dispatch.main.async { [averageDiastolic] in
            completion(averageDiastolic) // <===
        }
    }

    store.execute(query)
}
```

And then you'd call it along these lines:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var BloodPressure: UILabel!

    let healthValue = HealthValue()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        HealthControlAccess() // Not sure what this is doing. May need to wait for it to complete
    
        healthValue.bloodPressureDiastolic {
            print($0)
        }
    }
}
```